# How can i save the output of window_slider using while loop into a python data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

This is my code sample i am using https://github.com/imravishar/sliding_window to implement a sliding window on my dataset.

```
#technique with non-overlapping the values
dataset_slide=dataset_seq.tolist()
from window_slider import Slider
import numpy
list = numpy.array(dataset_slide)
bucket_size = 336
overlap_count = 0
slider = Slider(bucket_size,overlap_count)
slider.fit(list)       
while True:
    df = []
    window_data = slider.slide()
    print(window_data)
    if slider.reached_end_of_list(): break
df = pd.DataFrame(window_data, columns=['Consistency_Average'])
```

Where the **dataset_slide** contains 26295 rows of float consistency values. When the whole piece of code is executed **df** only contains last values of the **window_data** . I want to save all the **window_data** values into a dataframe.

For the quick info **window_data** will contain different windows when ever executed having 336 values in it until reached to 26295. I want to save them all for further use in machine learning classification algorithms.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed & replaced with `pandas`).

Comment: But i want to further use that saved data frame result for machine learning algorithms as mentioned.

Comment: Tags attract people with expertise in that field. Does your current code need someone with [tag:machine-learning] expertiese: No. So do not tag it as such.

Comment: Tags are about the *content* of the question, not its *context*; what you may need to use the answer for *afterwards* is irrelevant.